# Handle ComboBox TextChanged/DropDownOpened in ViewModel

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, combobox, mouseevent

I want to handle the DropDownOpened event of ComboBox in my ViewModel. How can I do that.

Basically my ItemSource of Comboxbox is bound to a collection. This collection can change, I do not know when it changes. So what I want to do is, I want to repopulate ComboBox every time User Clicks on the combobox (to open the dropdown). How can I do that in ViewModel.

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: `collection can change, I do not know when it changes. ` The collection has an event [`CollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx). [Sample](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587448/collectionchanged-sample). This is what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to handle UI events in WPF using view models is to implement `Attached Properties`. Here is an example that I use to monitor the `LostFocus` event... instead of passing the `EventArgs` object through to the view model, I am exposing a basic instance of `ICommand` (which you can implement in your view model) that will be called when the focus is lost from the relating `TextBox`:

```
public static DependencyProperty OnLostFocusProperty = DependencyProperty.
RegisterAttached("OnLostFocus", typeof(ICommand), typeof(TextBoxProperties), new 
UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnLostFocusChanged));

public static ICommand GetOnLostFocus(DependencyObject dependencyObject)
{
    return (ICommand)dependencyObject.GetValue(OnLostFocusProperty);
}

public static void SetOnLostFocus(DependencyObject dependencyObject, ICommand value)
{
    dependencyObject.SetValue(OnLostFocusProperty, value);
}

public static void OnLostFocusChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, 
DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
    if (e.OldValue == null && e.NewValue != null) textBox.LostFocus += TextBox_LostFocus;
    else if (e.OldValue != null && e.NewValue == null) textBox.LostFocus -= TextBox_LostFocus;
}

private static void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
    ICommand command = GetOnLostFocus(textBox);
    if (command != null && command.CanExecute(textBox)) command.Execute(textBox);
    e.Handled = false;
}
```

You would use it like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeValue}" Attached:TextBoxProperties.OnLostFocus="{Binding 
YourCommandName}" />
```

I'm sure that you can make a few changes to be able to apply it to your situation. If you are not familiar with `Attached Properties`, please view the [Attached Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) page at MSDN.