# Updating a ObservableCollection with the Data of another ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, observablecollection

I'm am currently working on a **WPF/XAML** project where i have the following problem:

I have a `ObservableCollection` which fetches it's data from a model as soon as the program starts and here is the deal.

How can i make another `ObservableCollection` which updates it's data on behalf of what you've chosen in the first `ObservableCollection`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribing to the `CollectionChanged` event and recreating the `ObservableCollection` should work:

```
public readonly ObservableCollection<string> Collection1 =
        new ObservableCollection<string>();

public readonly ObservableCollection<string> Collection2 =
        new ObservableCollection<string>();

public ViewModel() {
    Collection1.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Collection2.Clear();
        foreach (var x in Collection1) {
            Collection2.Add(x);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi @TaylorDrift, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation points to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should look into `ObservableCollection` events. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668610(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. it is not recommended to use `ObservableCollection` directly, a more
   straightforward way to use ObservableCollection capabilities from
   XAML in an application is to declare your own non-generic custom
   collection class that derives from ObservableCollection, and
   constrains it to a specific type
3. Examples can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588359/implementing-collectionchanged) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587448/collectionchanged-sample)

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! 
The links has been helpful.