# wpf binding issue with ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding DataViews}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <DataGrid MaxHeight="500" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,10,0" MaxColumnWidth="450"
                                          RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowSql}" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyleSQL}"
                                          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource StyleDataGridColumnHeaderDefault}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                                          IsReadOnly="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Page},Path=Locked}"
                                          RowEditEnding="DataGrid_RowEditEnding" >
                                    <DataGrid.CommandBindings>
                                        <CommandBinding Command="Copy" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"></CommandBinding>
                                    </DataGrid.CommandBindings>
                                    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
                                        <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="Copy"></KeyBinding>
                                    </DataGrid.InputBindings>
                                </DataGrid>
                                <GridSplitter Background="Red" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeDirection="Rows" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext"></GridSplitter>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch"></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
```

hi, I need to have the updated data in the `DataGrid_RowEditEnding` event, since the `e.Row` doesn't have the updated data, so I thought about adding `<ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding DataViews, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" >` but it doesn't work, where am I wrong?

Comment: You will find loads of edge cases if you try and validate data as it's entered directly into a datagrid. My usual approach is to make the datagrid read only and the user edits the selected item in a different panel overlay.

Comment: unfortunately it is a datagrid that derives from a database query, I have to go through the datagrid

Comment: You should check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3938040/13448212) as it seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the updated value in the `CellEditEnding` event handler if you just set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property of the bindings to `PropertyChanged`.

If you are using auto-generated columns, you could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` for the `DataGrid` to do this:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridBoundColumn dataGridBoundColumn = e.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;
    if (dataGridBoundColumn != null)
    {
        dataGridBoundColumn.Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName) { UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged };
    }
}
```

Comment: that you know there is no way to do this from xaml?

Comment: You can't set attributes on bindings using a style and you're using automatic generation of columns.